# Java And GhostDriver : Hide Console and Logs

Tags: java, selenium, phantomjs, ghostdriver

I try to hide the console and the log of GhostDriver in java...

```
- Windows 7.
- JDK is in 1.7.0_75 version.
- PhantomJS 1.9.7 is include with it path.
- GhostDriver 1.1.0 is include in an Eclipse Java SE Project.
- Selenium 2.43.1 is include in an Eclipse Java SE Project.
```

Is there a way?

I tried "--webdriver-loglevel=OFF" and "--webdriver-loglevel=NONE" in cli_args but it doesn't works...

I tried java -jar myJar.jar > myFile.txt but it doesn't works...

Is there others ways or may be an error?

An example of the code :

```
    WebDriver driver;
    DesiredCapabilities dCaps;
    dCaps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    dCaps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
    dCaps.setCapability("takesScreenshot", true);
    dCaps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, new String[] {"--ignore-ssl-errors=true", "--ssl-protocol=tlsv1", "--web-security=false", "--webdriver-loglevel=OFF", "--webdriver-loglevel=NONE"});
    dCaps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, phantom);
    driver = new PhantomJSDriver(dCaps);
```

And the logs (with VM arguments) :

```
   mai 18, 2015 2:09:48 PM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init>
   INFOS: executable: C:\Users\212428788\workspace\BigBrowser\phantomjs-1.9.7-windows\phantomjs.exe
   mai 18, 2015 2:09:48 PM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init>
   INFOS: port: 48921
   mai 18, 2015 2:09:48 PM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init>
   INFOS: arguments: [--ignore-ssl-errors=true, --ssl-protocol=tlsv1, --web-security=false, --webdriver-loglevel=OFF, --webdriver-loglevel=NONE, --webdriver=48921, --webdriver-logfile=C:\Users\212428788\workspace\BigBrowser\phantomjsdriver.log]
   mai 18, 2015 2:09:48 PM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init>
   INFOS: environment: {}
   PhantomJS is launching GhostDriver...
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you try adding the VM argument in eclipse and check? From your logs, I can see that half of it has been silenced.

Comment: I did it and edited it

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found the answer, just install the jar as Windows Service...

Answer (score 4):

See if the below steps work for you (answer from [this](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/issues/338) thread):

- Create a String array like this:

  ```
  String[] phantomArgs = new  String[] {
          "--webdriver-loglevel=NONE"
  };
  ```
- Add the below line to your `DesiredCapabilities`:

  ```
  capabilities.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, phantomArgs);
  ```
- My config for PhantomJSDriver is something like this:

  ```
  //set binary path of phantomJS driver
  DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();       
  capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
  capabilities.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, "drivers/phantomjs.exe");
  capabilities.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_PAGE_SETTINGS_PREFIX,"Y");
  capabilities.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, phantomArgs);
  capabilities.setCapability("phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:16.0) Gecko/20121026 Firefox/16.0");

  //intialize driver and set capabilties
  PhantomJSDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(capabilities);
  ```
- Right click on your project and choose **Run As->Run Configurations->Arguments** and add the VM argument `-Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties` to VM Arguments:

  [image]
- Click on **Apply** and then **Run**

Comment: Thanks for the VM arguments but it doesn't works for me

Comment: This is working fine for me. What do you mean by "*it doesn't works for me*"? Did you add the VM argument? Did you add the line `capabilities.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, phantomArgs);
`? How much log you are seeing? Please be **specific**

Comment: Yes, my cli_args are Ok, and i have the same code for the capabilities... But PhantomJS and GhostDriver Log in console are not disable... Do you want the exact code and log ?

Comment: Yes, if you could edit your question and add these details, it would help.